# spurious space in edit diff

Tags: bug, edit-history

This is a very minor bug, but perhaps nevertheless worth reporting: In revision $5$ of [these revisions](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/246981/revisions), there's a space before the slash in the title on the left-hand side even though, as you can see from revision $4$, there was no space there before the edit; the space was introduced by the edit and should only appear on the right-hand side.

Comment: Just for clarification: you mean to say that in revision 4 there was no space before the `/` in the title. In your edit you _did not_ put in a space before the `/` in the title. But the saved version now shows a space there, and the diff cannot tell the difference?

Comment: @Willie: I *did* put a space before the `/` in the title in the edit corresponding to revision $5$. After revision $4$ (which corresponds to an edit by someone else) there was no space; after revision $5$ there is a space; so the diff for revision $5$ should show a space on the right-hand side but not on the left-hand side, whereas it shows a space on both sides.